# "The weak shall be cut down by their peers"

Tags: bible, verse-identification

I bumped into a Facebook post today mocking a particular Bible passage, quoting:

> The weak shall be cut down by their peers

They never provided any reference and it's one I don't recall ever reading. A Google search doesn't seem to return anything either.

What passage is this and what is it referring to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because verse identification questions are off-topic unless you clearly identify all the phrases you searched for.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such passage in the Bible - more likely someone has twisted and perverted Psalm 37:11 which says:

> "But the meek will inherit the land and enjoy great peace."

Another similar passage is in Matthew 5:5 (the Beatitudes):

> "Blessed are the meek, for they will inherit the earth."

That post on Facebook was no quote from the Bible.  If it had been a quote, it would have provided the book, the chapter and the verse.  More like wishful thinking on the part of those who mock, scoff and ridicule Christianity.